# How can I use a custom name for a vue component?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

The component I want to use with a custom name is defined as:

`@/components/MyCustomName.vue`

```
<template lang="">
  <div>I'm here</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'a-custom-name',
  inheritAttrs: false,
  customOptions: {}
}
</script>

<script setup></script>

<style lang=""></style>
```

and I try to use it by doing:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <a-custom-name class="the-class"></a-custom-name>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>

import MyCustomName from '@/components/MyCustomName.vue'

</script>

<style scoped>

.the-class {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>
```

However, this generates a warning which states:

```
[vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: a-custom-name
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <HomePage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

and `I'm here` doesn't show up.

If I drop the custom name and just use `<MyCustomName...` directly, it works.

What simple thing have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing as default and making an alias:

```
import { default as aCustomName } from '@/components/MyCustomName.vue'
```